# "S" symbol appearing on Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I have created a Maven project using spring-bootstrap and using SVN, I don't know why a symbol "S" appears as below on some files in my project.

Am using eclipse JUNO.

Comment: What plugin are you using for SVN? I think that the "S" just means that file is under version control

Comment: @Ravi Kumar Y Are you using spring

Comment: Spring Beans decorator.